# How to destroy session on refreshing url or copy same and try to open in other tab of same browser in java based web application?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, session-cookies, servlet-filters

I want to logout existing application if user try to refresh already open page or copy url from url tab and paste into another tab of same browser.

basically I want to restrict my web application to open in multiple tab with same session.

Comment: Is it a JSF application?

Comment: No David it is normal jsp servlet application on spring framework.

Comment: how you are maintaining the user session details? you can store the session id in table and if user tries to refresh/logout/hit the same url in other tab then delete the session details from the table. If user tries to login again , check if there is any entry present in that table or not if present then delete the entry and make a new one.